# Parallel requests same session django

Tags: django

I am building a site where the user is sent a random item. Each view will involve updating lot of variables as to what was seen last and which categories next random pick will be from. But when I thought about it I felt this code will work only if request occurs one after the other and there would be a problem if user makes parallel requests. I am wondering if this problem is real or django handles it by queuing parallel requests. If this is real then I am thinking of redirecting the new request(second or third parallel request) to "one request per session page". I know the chance of a user making parallel requests and disrupting the logic is small but still I have to take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Django's job to make these decisions. This has more to do with the server technologies you are going to use(e.g. nginx, gunicorn, postgresql, etc).

If you design your app the way web apps are meant to function(i.e. **stateless**) you shouldn't need to worry and all the concurrency related stuff should be dealt transparently from your "single source of truth", which in your case should be the database.

If your web app's design/logic does not adhere to these principles, it is most probably flawed and you need to redesign it.

If you really think your app is special-case, give us some more concrete examples, or even better, show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel requests for same user are possible for Django application so you'll have to handle it yourself. Good principle is to try to avoid having state on backend. You might consider if you can re-design your frontend to handle the state. However this is not always possible.

One way is to keep state in backend is to use a quick in-memory database like Memcached, MongoDB or Redis. I believe these will allow atomic operations if used correctly. One option is to use [Djangos cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/cache/) that exposes atomic operations (at least when backed by memcached).

Comment: I'm a little confused. What do you mean by "Parallel requests are possible for Django"? Aren't possible for all web apps? Isn't it something you configure with your web container of choice(e.g. gunicorn)? Do you do threaded programming in django? Also what's the difference between django sessions(regardless of the backend) and the other things you mention? Or are your implicitly talking about the django session framework?

Comment: @rantanplan Thank's for comments. 1. Yes, parallel requests are possible for most webapps. The OP asked if django somehow queues the requests from same user instead of processing them in parallel, I answered that. 2. I do threaded programming in Django sometimes, but it isn't relevant here. 3. I'm not talking about sessions framework, what I'm talking is closer to cache functionality. I didn't see any reference how you can do atomic operations with Django sessions so I didn't mention it, feel free to suggest if I'm wrong and I'll update the answer (I tried reading the docs).

Comment: I got initially a bit confused because I thought that you were proposing writing code that handles the concurrency of requests. I'm no stranger to Redis and caching, I just wonder how you can keep state with it and if it makes it simpler or if it perplexes things more. Is there an example you can point to? I genuinely don't know if what you propose is wrong or not, I only know that I've never come across something similar and this intrigues me.

Comment: @rantanplan For example if you want a counter that counts how many requests user has made, you can use cache's incr() method that increments the counter atomically. I believe this would not be 100% reliable if done with Django sessions (two simultanous requests may update at same time counting as only one).

Comment: Yeah I get what you're saying. Well this depends entirely on how you handle your transactions(manual/autocommit/per request) and the session backend of your choice. e.g. if you chose to store session information in your rdbms, this is easily achievable, although in the example you offered I, too, would prefer some of redis's atomic operations.

Comment: But more to the point, I sense that the OP is not talking about something so trivial as a request counter, but that he has some business flow tied to the order of the requests, which seems wrong to me.

Comment: Good to know that you can do it with sessions, I haven't verified it myself and docs don't mention much about transactions with sessions, so I didn't mention it. I'm just wondering how it works since Transaction-middleware is below Session-middleware by default, so normally having transaction over the session isn't possible. Maybe it's possible to switch them (middleware-layers) around)?

Comment: From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests, `So if you use the session middleware after the transaction middleware, session creation will be part of the transaction.` So yes as with most middleware you can decide its scope.